# Receive a notification when the phone goes offline

Tags: vpn

How do I get a notification when my phone actually has no internet service?
I'm using an **Always On** VPN connection that sometimes silently goes offline (it's a known problem).

- OS: Android 10 (Anroid One)
- No root
- Without Google account
- F-droid or other FOSS source are OK

Looks like [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) can do this but it's only available in the Google Play.
I would prefer a method that does not require additional software.

Comment: You can download Automate from APKMirror or using Raccoon apk downloader.